# How to ensure for loop loops through entire dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to write a loop through a pandas dataframe that takes the mean (ignoring NaN's) of specific columns (16:20) in the current row and appends it to a list (that I later want to make a new column in my dataframe). My code is as below:

```
import numpy as np


n = 0
list = []
for row in df:
    list.append(
                np.nanmean(
                           df.iloc[n, 16:20]
                                            )
                )
    n += 1

len(list)
>>> 87

len(df)
>>> 20434
```

As you can see, the for loop stops after 86 loops - why does it stop? Shouldn't I receive a list that has 20434 entries?

Comment: Please read [mre]. We don't have your data, so we can't actually "see" this. Try to figure out a smaller data set that causes the problem. For example, if you remove the first half of the DataFrame, does the error still occur? What if you keep only the first half? If you have a half that causes the problem, keep going until you have something as small as possible that shows the problem. Then provide code that allows us to make and test that DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for n, row in enumerate(df):` but it's clearly not the best solution!

Prefer:

```
out = df.iloc[:, 16:20].mean(axis=1)  # Remember 20 is excluded in Python
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work off of the index:

```
list = []
for index in df.index:
    list.append(
                np.nanmean(
                           pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[index, 16:20])
                           )
                )

len(list)
>>> 20434
```

Comment: Take care: pd.to_numeric should raise an exception here AND your loop could work only and only because index label is equal to index position (label 0 = position 0, label 1 = position 1, and so on)